# edit button not show in Orchard Zones 1.9.2

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I download Orchard.Web.1.9.2 and I want add Edit button in the upper right corner.
In tutorials show that you need to log in as Admin and enable modules (Content Control Wrapper and Enable Widget Control Wrapper). But I still didn't see this button.

[image]

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I didn't change default theme (The Theme Machine)

Comment: If you're sure that the features were really enabled, then you should file a bug.